# How do I join a collection if I don't know its type at compile-time?

Tags: c#, .net

We have a boxed list of strings:

```
object myList = new List<string> { "str1", "str2" };
```

We want to use `String.Join` and obtain `"str1,str2"`. If we do

```
String.Join(",",myList)
```

It returns `` System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] `` instead.
How do we deal with this without changing the declaration of `myList`?

This is just a specific example. The type need not always be `List<string>`, we need to do `myList.GetType()` to obtain that info.

Comment: _"object myList = new List<string>"_ - why do you want to do that?

Comment: This is just an MWE. The main code involves reflection and we deal with objects.

Comment: Um, cast it back to `List<string>`?

Comment: _"This is just an MWE. The main code involves reflection and we deal with objects"_ - so this is an example of a _XY question._  Consider posting your _actual_ problem

Comment: `List<string> myList = new List<string> { "str1", "str2" };`

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine please see edit

Comment: @MickyD the actual issue is not much more than this. We want a string from the boxed list which is obtained using FieldInfo.GetValue, and then we write that to a cell of a .csv file. But right now it prints System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] instead of the actual list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't know the type of the boxed collection, you could write a helper method to unbox and join it:

```
public string UnboxAndJoin(string separator, object obj)
{
    if (obj is IEnumerable enumerable)
    {
        return string.Join(separator, enumerable.Cast<object>());
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Object is not an IEnumerable");
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
object myList = new List<string> { "str1", "str2" };
Console.WriteLine(UnboxAndJoin(",", myList));       // str1,str2
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `` System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] `` and that's the expected result in your case.

The overload resolution for `String.Join` is chosing the following overload in your case:

```
public static string Join (string? separator, params object?[] values);
```

As documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-6.0#system-string-join(system-string-system-object())) the [`Object.ToString()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-6.0) is called on each object of the `values` parameter. Quotes from the documentation:

> The string representation of each object in the array is derived by
> calling that object's ToString method.

The only object in the `values` parameter is an instance of the `List<string>` class. This class doesn't override the base implementation of `ToString()` defined in the `Object` class, so the fully qualified name of the class is returned when `ToString()` is called on any instance of the class itself.

That's why you are getting the string `` System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] `` as the output of your code.

If your desired output is the string `"str1,str2"`, then the overload of `String.Join` that you really want to call is the following:

```
public static string Join (string? separator, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string?> values);
```

In order to call this overload, you need to downcast the `myList` variable to the `List<string>` type:

```
String.Join(",", (List<string>) myList)
```

If don't know the actual type of the object that you have in the `myList` variable, you can be defensive and do the following:

```
if (myList is IEnumerable<string> values) 
{
  var message = String.Join(",", values);
  Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```